# How can i forbid tab switching the focus into a NSView control

Tags: cocoa, macos, focus, nsview

I have a sidebar NSOutlineView in my main window. I want the user to be able to switch the
focus with the tab key through all views in the main window, but he should not be able to give the NSOutlineView the focus with a tab key.

I know that with

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyView { return NO; }
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder { return NO; }
```

i can disable the focus for the view but i this completely disables the view. I want the user to be able to use the keys in the source list (by clicking into the list). Just put the source list out of the tab order.

There is also a hot key to give the source list the focus programmatically, which doesn't work either if i set use the functions above.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out which view has this view as its `nextKeyView`, and set its `nextKeyView` to something else. Then do the same for `previousKeyView` so that the user cannot *shift-*tab into it.